# How to use v-model property of vuejs with laravel blade file?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-8, laravel-blade, v-model

I am using vuejs cdn in my laravel blade file. Now, I want to bind `v-model` on my html input fields like text and select tag. here is my code how i am trying to use v-model on select  tag. This process isn't working for me. thanks in advance

```html
@section('script')
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#purchaseApp',
            data() {
                return {
                   purchase_items:'',
                   supplier:'',
                }
            },
            methods: {

            },
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

```html
<div class="widget-content widget-content-area">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Supplier</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select name="supplier" v-model="supplier" class="form-control suppliers" >
                <option value="" selected disabled>Select Supplier</option>
                 <option value="shibbir">shibbir</option>
                 <option value="ripon">ripon</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what's not working?? what error you are exactly getting??

Comment: v-model is working in input type text fields. But, it doesn't working in select tag.

Comment: remove the selected attribute from the first option. `<option value="" disabled>Select Supplier</option>`. v-model handles the selected attribute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution of problem. There I used select-2 plugin. For that reason, v-model wasn't working.